# Entity Framework Core: load full hierarchy

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1, entity-framework-core-2.2

Having a self referencing table, with a ParentId attribute which holds the id of the parent record, what can I do so that using ef I will load into each parent its children.

What I want is to transform this cte which will return the full hierarchy as a collection.

```
var queryString = @"
        ;WITH cte AS (
            SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Folders] _f WHERE _f.[Id] = @id

            UNION ALL

            SELECT _c.* FROM [dbo].[Folders] _c
            INNER JOIN cte _cte
            ON _cte.[Id] = _c.[ParentFolderId]
        )

        SELECT * FROM cte";


return await this.Entities.FromSql(new RawSqlString(queryString), new SqlParameter("id", id)).ToListAsync();
```

into something that will somehow load the hierarchy of children into their parents, keeping at the same time the performance of one trip to db.

```
class Folder
{ 
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int? FolderId { get; set; }
     public Folder Folder { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<Folder> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Hierarchy example

```
- Main (Id: 1 / ParentId: null) 
     - C1 (2/1) 
           - C11 (4/2) 
                  - C111 (7/4)
           - C12 (5/2)
     - C2 (3/1) 
           - C21 (6/3) 
                  - C211 (8/6)
```

Configured relation

```
builder.Ignore(prop => prop.Folder);
builder.HasOne(prop => prop.Folder).WithMany(prop => prop.Children).HasForeignKey(fk => fk.FolderId);
```

Comment: EF can't generate this CTE. If you use it eg with `FromSqlRaw` or `FromSqlInterpolated`, EF Core may be able to use the IDs to reconstruct the hierarchy, as long as the DbContext entities are configured correctly (relations etc)

Comment: Another option is to use `hierarchyid` instead of self-referencing and the [EFCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId](https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId) package. Querying will definitely be easier and faster. Even if you decide at some point to remove that package it will be a lot easier to write hierarchical SQL queries with `hierarchyid`

Comment: I dont see FromSqlRaw nor FromSqlInterpolated being available to version 2.x of EF core. Will look into the HierarchyId library, thanks.

Comment: In 2.0 it's `FromSql` for both, and you have to be extra careful if you use interpolated strings, or you may end up with a nice SQL injection. That's why in EF Core 3 there are two separate methods for interpolated or parameterized queries

Answer (score 3):

If you want the entire hierarchy in one query, that's easy.  Just retrieve all the Folders and if Change Tracking is enabled EF will fix-up all the relationships. IE if you just run

```
var folders = db.Set<Folder>().ToList();
```

You'll have the whole hierarcy with all the Navigation Properties populated.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by retrieving all folders ? I guess you are taking about the folders of the looked up folder ?

Answer (score -2):

You can get the whole hierarchy with this query:

```
var hierarchy = db.Set<Folder>().Include(f => f.Children).ToList();
```